# Avoid Twitter SMS verification to access API?

Tags: api, twitter, verification

I need the SMS verification to get access to the developer tools and receive an API key and such. However, I never receive SMS from them with the verification. Nor do online sms services work -- nothing ever arrives?

I wrote to their support more than two weeks ago. No dice either, no answer at all.

Is there any way go to around this stupid SMS verification to get an API key? This is really terribly designed.

Comment: Which country are you in? ISTR that some places aren't supported.

Comment: Singapore. And yeah doesn't work here it appears, but I tried online services like Twilio. Still same :/

Comment: Same occurs for me as well.

Comment: It suddenly worked for me. I am not sure, I think their service was just down.